# Select case not working

Tags: vb.net

```
   If decItemWeight > 0 Then
        Select Case decShippingPrice
            Case Is <= 2
                decShippingPrice = 3.69D
            Case Is <= 4
                decShippingPrice = 4.86D
            Case Is <= 6
                decShippingPrice = 5.63D
            Case Is <= 8
                decShippingPrice = 5.98D
            Case Is <= 10
                decShippingPrice = 6.28D
            Case Is <= 30
                decShippingPrice = 15.72D
        End Select
    End If
```

Above is the code for a Visual Basic I'm working on. When I enter a value above 2, the price should be greater than the initial value of $3.69. However, the program only seems to be running the first case. Therefore, regardless of the value I enter, the number $3.69 will always be printed on the screen. Any ideas on how I can address the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing to the wrong variable.  Use decItemWeight instead:

```
If decItemWeight > 0 Then
    Select Case decItemWeight 
        Case Is <= 2
            decShippingPrice = 3.69D
        Case Is <= 4
           decShippingPrice = 4.86D
        Case Is <= 6
            decShippingPrice = 5.63D
        Case Is <= 8
            decShippingPrice = 5.98D
        Case Is <= 10
            decShippingPrice = 6.28D
        Case Is <= 30
            decShippingPrice = 15.72D
    End Select
End If
```